# Copying file path of current directory in CMD(DOSKEY)

Tags: windows, cmd, doskey

I'm writing DOSKEY with multiple commands, separated by $T, and I need to copy PATH of current directory to cipbord(so I could use it latter outside of CMD) and to continue with commands. I have tried `chdir | clip` by it brakes commands after. Basicly a need `copy as path` from windows explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the command as a DOSKEY macro, then you need to escape any special characters like `|`. Also, the $T does not seem to work after a pipe, but `^&` does work.

```
doskey macroName=echo Command1^&cd^|clip^&echo Command2
```

Answer (score 10):

would

```
echo %cd% |clip
```

do what you want?

Comment: It does not work. The problem is in that `clip` does some thing else it just does not copy text, it forces paste or something similar. When I type `chdir | clip` to command line I got `is not recognized as an internal or external command,` error, Like it's auto pasting text. I think that that's somehow breaking the DOSKEY command.

Comment: Since you don't mention your platform: I would note that clip.exe is a built-in Windows tool on at least Windows 7. I don't know about Vista.

Comment: @Magoo's command works just fine for me here. It echoes the current directory (`%CD%` dynamic variable) to standard output, which is then stored in the clipboard.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - But it does not work if used in definition of a DOSKEY macro. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24463570/1012053).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
doskey CC=echo ^%CD^%^|clip
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that Magoo's answer worked except that echo appends a newline to any text. You can use the set command to prevent this behavior.

```
echo | set /p=%cd% | clip
```